# echo a specific set of rows from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a front end dev playing around with back end so bear with. I'm just creating simple app that displays the team line ups for a football match. I've created the tables in the database and can loop through all 22 players for a match. However, I only want to display the first 11 in one div and the second 11 in another.

Here's my code so far:

```
    <?php

try {

    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=euro_missing_men','root','');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die('Sorry, database issue');
}




$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM `game` g 
    JOIN team t on (g.id = t.game_id) 
    JOIN team_name tn on (t.team_id = tn.id)
    JOIN position p on (t.position_id = p.id)
');

$results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    echo $row->player, "<br/>";
}


?>
```

This produces the following:

```
McKimmie
Calderwood
Hendry
Boyd
McKinlay
McCall
McAllister
Collins
Spencer
Durie
Seaman
Neville
Adams
Southgate
Pearce
Anderton
Ince
Gascoigne
McManaman
Sheringham
Shearer
```

But I want to separate them. I understand there's probably a better way to do this but for the purpose of the exercise I'd like to echo the first 11 names in one div and the second 11 names in another.

Thanks.

Comment: i don;t think low level means what you think it means. this is all relatively high-level stuff.

Comment: Are You trying to paginate this stuf by any chance ? If so use LIMIT and OFFSET in your query (or shorten LIMIT with two param where secound acts as offset) instead of loading all the data at once. if you want to prevent page to reaload on pagination change use AJAX to load only this part of page. If not.. forget I asked :)

Answer (score 3):

```
// create a counter
$i = 0;

// echo the opening div
echo "<div>";
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    echo $row->player, "<br/>";
    if ( $i++ == 11 ) echo "</div><div>"; // increment the counter and at the 11th iteration close the div and start a new one
}
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Why not combine the increment `$i++` into the comparison? `if ( $i++ == 11 )` ...

Comment: And yes, `===` will work, but no need for the strict comparison, right? `==` would work just as well?

Comment: Thank you Pamblam. It does work but for an offset i assume as it works as it should with 10. I am actually missing the first row though for some reason (I was in the original question just hadn't noticed). So only 21 players are shown. Any ideas why?

Comment: Ignore above comment, was querying the db twice.

Answer (score 2):

This assumes you might have more than 22.  If you only have 22 exactly, then @pamblam has the simpler answer.

If you wanted to divide them into groups of 11, you might use the [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator:

```
var $count = 1;
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    // After every 11th row, echo a closing div / open a new div
    if ( ! ($count++ % 11) ) {
        echo '</div><div>';
    }

    // Don't use break tags, you can't style them well.
    echo '<p>' . $row->player . "</p>";
}
```

Or, another way would be to split up the results into arrays:

```
$results = $query->fetchAll();

$divs = array_chunk($results, 11);

foreach( $divs AS $div ) {
    echo '<div>';
    foreach ( $div AS $row ) {
        echo '<p>' . $row->player . '</p>';
    }
    echo '<div>';
}
```

Comment: woah getting all fancy with the modulus operator, why not just `===` though?

Comment: makes sense, though i would imagine the number wouldn't vary too much for a fooseball team. aren;t they only allowed to have a certain number of guys?

Comment: I think you'll need parenthesis, something like `if ( !($count++ % 11) ) {`

Answer (score 1):

Simple split the results? then loop each one?

```
$results = $query->fetchAll();

$team1 = array_slice($results, 0, 11);

$team2 = array_slice($results, 11);
```

as suggested array_chunck

```
$results = $query->fetchAll();

$teams = array_chunk($results, 11);
```

And to output this

```
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$teams = array_chunk($results, 11);

foreach($teams as $team) {
    echo '<div>';
    foreach($team as $player) {
        echo $player->name . '<br />';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Nice.  I like it.  Why not go with [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) instead? Simpler even...

Comment: I do like the simplicity of this. Struggling with looping through the array however! Seem to just get undefined index or property of non object errors?

Comment: Love it, seems to work great! Thanks. (Though "name" should be "player", but can blame my awful naming convention for that!)

Answer (score 0):

You could always do something basic like this:

```
   <?php

try {

    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=euro_missing_men','root','');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die('Sorry, database issue');
}




$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM `game` g 
    JOIN team t on (g.id = t.game_id) 
    JOIN team_name tn on (t.team_id = tn.id)
    JOIN position p on (t.position_id = p.id)
');

$results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$upto = 0;
echo "<div>"; //Start the divs
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $upto ++; //add 1 to upto
    if($upto % 11 == 0) //if 11 results
        echo "</div><div>"; //create new div
    echo $row->player, "<br/>";

}
echo "</div>"; //close div


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add increment. And if $i <=11 put player in first div. In another way put them to second div.

```
    $results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $i = 0;

    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
     $i++;
     if($i <= 11){
        echo "{$i} of 22".$row->player."<br/>";
     }
     else{
        echo "{$i} of 22".$row->player."<br/>";
     }
    }
```